# Not able to call WCF service from the Azure logic app

Tags: wcf, azure-logic-apps

We have a requirement to call the WCF web service from the logic app.
We have achieved the calling by using the Azure function code but we need to achieve the same by using the Azure logic app.

We have tried the custom connector SOAP (PREVIEW) feature to call our WCF web service but it is returning an error message i.e. 
{
  "error": {
    "code": "a:InvalidSecurity",
    "message": "An error occurred when verifying security for the message."
}
}
even we have provided the username and password.

Does anyone have an IDEA about it?

OR Does anyone share any help to use "SOAP pass-through" and steps to call the WCF web service by using manual soap call?

Comment: Where is your WCF service? and could you please share some demo code?

Comment: If the WCF service is not on-prem, I would also explore calling it using just an Http Request action. I'd suggest you to inspect your Http request coming from the Azure Function and try to replicate the call by adding the same SOAP Envelope around your message and the corresponding http headers. However, depending on the bindings of the WCF Service, the complexity of writing that SOAP Envelope can vary. HTH